# Code does not run at all times in php contact form page

Tags: javascript, php

I have uploaded a contact form with name, e-mail address, phone number, message (textarea), captcha text, and a submit button. Given below is the click code of submit button

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    var code = <?php echo($_SESSION['secure']);?>;
    var scode = $('input[name=code]').val();

    if(code != scode) {
        output = "Security code doesn't match. Retry";
        $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
    } else {
        //get input field values
        var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val(); 
        var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
        var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

        var proceed = true;
        if(user_name==""){ 
            $('input[name=name]').css('background-color','yellow');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_email==""){ 
            $('input[name=email]').css('background-color','yellow'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_phone=="") {    
            $('input[name=phone]').css('background-color','yellow'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_message=="") {  
            $('textarea[name=message]').css('background-color','yellow'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_phone=="") {    
            $('input[name=phone]').css('background-color','yellow'); 
            proceed = false;
        }

    }
});
```

The problem is, i need to do a few manual refreshes to run this code. I tried replacing the whole click code with some other codes (like a simple message alert etc.) and it works well.
could you please tell me why this code isn't running all the times?
Same happens when running from the server and through apache. Please pardon me for putting the whole code here, it is too large.

Comment: Is there any console error???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could lie in line 2, where you assign a value to the `code` variable. You should put quotes around the PHP code or else it throws an error whenever the code is not a number. I suspect that the security codes are sometimes alphanumeric and nometimes only numeric and that's why it sometimes work and sometimes not. Let me know if I'm right.

To illustrate the problem: This is the problematic line:

```
var code = <?php echo($_SESSION['secure']);?>;
```

Let's assume that the current security code is "1234", so the line becomes:

```
var code = 1234;
```

This is perfectly fine. But given a security code of "abcd", you end up with this:

```
var code = abcd;
```

There probably is no variable called `abcd` in your code, so you get a ReferenceError and the function execution stops. The solution to this is, as I said, to put the PHP code in quotes:

```
var code = "<?php echo($_SESSION['secure']);?>";
```

This will result in:

```
var code = "abcd";
```

Comment: Thank you Butt4cak3. You are correct. I did what you said and it works fine now. Thank you very much.I love the way you illustrate the solution.